# Remove multiple characters from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this: "22 - 11 - 33".

I would like to remove all the dashes '-' and all the spaces to return a string like this "221133".

I know there is a replace() method but as far as I know it only removes one thing passed into it. I would like to remove more than one character type.

Comment: use Regex with `.replace()` https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-string-replace-example-with-regex/

Comment: What is the problem with [this your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70700324/modern-way-of-removing-certain-characters-from-a-string?noredirect=1) about this same subject? There's a nice comment about `replaceAll` ...

Comment: @Teemu it didn't get an answer?

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Then the correct action is to edit the question? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415102/1169519

Comment: @Teemu I agree, although it's been deleted now

Comment: @mplungjan sure thing, I just gave a reason as to why the OP would make another question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+regex?+replace+keep+digits+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

`"22 - 11 - 33".replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');`
should work

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex replace for that:

```js
console.log(
  "22 - 11 - 33".replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
);
```

---

`[^\d]` - replace anything that is not number
`\d` - matches numbers groups, similar to `[0-9]`
`/g` - replace all matches